# Install Ubuntu alongside Win 8.1 on separate physical drives and dual-boot?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, disk

I have a PC with an OEM install of Win 8 updated to 8.1.  It has 3 physical hard drives in it.  The drive where Windows is installed has a LOT of partitions on it already.

Can I install Ubuntu on a different physical hard drive than Windows, and be able to dual-boot?

I am able to boot to a live USB of Ubuntu 14.04, so I think I'm about ready to proceed.  But if I can make my installation easier by using a different physical drive, I'd like to do that.

Comment: Partition in advance with gpt partitioning, and make sure to include an efi partition, FAT32, with boot flag as first partition. Something Else may still install grub2's boot files into the efi partition on the Windows partition. Otherwise standard Something Else install. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace and: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Thanks.  All disks are already GPT so that sounds like a good plan.

Comment: @oldfred in case you don't see my comment below, I would like to express my profound gratitude for your advice.  I performed the install and it went without a hitch.  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you **can** install ubuntu on a different drive. but you need to know something before you proceed. new *EFI* systems these days (or UEFI) has **Fastboot/General-optimization** option. that makes the PC boot faster. but if you turn this **ON** and install ubuntu on a different drive, you will get the grub prompt saying *"no such device"* error. Reason is that **Fastboot/General-optimization** only recognize **one HDD** at boot time. I'll explain the error you will get, assume that your *windows* disc is **sda** and *ubuntu* disk is **sdb**.

- sda1 recovery (windows)
- **sda2 EFI**
- **sda3 Windows**
- **sdb1 ubuntu**
- sdb2 home
- sdb3 swap

in this situation... EFI firmware can read the **grub** *EFI* entry in the **sda2** partiton but it leads to **sdb1** disk and fastboot is **ON**, you will surely get *"no such device"* error. So you have to turn off fast boot option in EFI firmware.

Comment: I want to really, really thank both you and @oldfred for your sage advice.  I just performed the install according to the directions from both of you and it was flawless.  Thanks!!