# What is the recommened way to dual-boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu on two HD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, ssd

I am building a computer and have a 1 TB hard drive and a 250GB SSD. I would like to install both OS on the SSD and have them both be able to access the HD. Would it work to install both on the SSD and just partition the HD in half?

How should I dual-boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu on two storage devices?

Comment: Check out this answer, I just did this same thing (except 2 hdds, no ssd).  Their advice was good, it worked first time: http://askubuntu.com/questions/591193/install-ubuntu-alongside-win-8-1-on-separate-physical-drives-and-dual-boot

Comment: @organicMarble Thanks for the link! I'm planning on installing both on the SSD and using the HD for supplementation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's definitely possible and the Ubuntu installer allows it when choosing the option "something else". Just plan the partition layout of both drives accordingly. You can create the partitions beforehand with GParted, if you feel more comfortable with that tool.

In my personal experience, the Windows installer doesn't like some partitioning schemes (with its boot and recovery partitions and whatnot), even though they should be fine, so

1. I usually start out with an empty partition table and then create the partition(s) for Windows from its installer with the desired size(s),
2. then I create the partition(s) for Linux/Ubuntu from a live DVD/USB (optionally), and
3. finally I install Ubuntu with the "something else" option, creating and/or assigning all the partitions as needed.

Answer (score 0):

For a beginner I would recommend disconnecting the 1 TB from the motherboard while installing windows and ubuntu on the SSD. I would partition the disk before installing either OS. Also for a beginner I would install windows first. Then install Ubuntu. If you are not a beginner and are versed in partitioning disks and OS installs then disregard the previous. Connect the 1 TB disk again. Once you are done boot to windows 8.1. You will want to disable Fast Startup because in this mode when windows shuts down it hibernates all your hard disks rather than truly powering them off. When you boot ubuntu after a windows 8.1 shutdown you will not be able to access any NTFS partitions from ubuntu. You will get a read/write error saying that disks were not shut down properly to boot into windows and correct this. This does not apply to the Restart function. Here is a [link](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) to do this. I used option 1