# Installing ubuntu os on a different drive than windows os during dual boot setup

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I would like to know if ubuntu could be installed in other drive than C: ( which reads healthy, boot, page dump , ....) and other drivers which read as only primary drive. It is because I don't utilize precious C: for something other than windows source and program files.

Also just curious, could both OS use some common drive in dual boot . For example there is a G: drive of 100 gb which would have contents shared by both the OS's.

Sorry for a noob question but most of the tutorials out there install in the same drive ( or shrink) the C drive

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done.  My main PC has Windows 8.1 installed on one physical drive and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on a different physical drive.  There is a third physical drive which is accessible from either OS.  This all works great.

However, both OS's did store their EFI boot information in the same partition on one of the drives.  I do not know if it has to be this way. I had created an EFI partition on Ubuntu's physical drive, but the installer used the one on the Windows physical drive. I was told this might happen, and it did.

I have the shared physical drive formatted as ntfs, because this started out as a Windows PC.  This may be required anyway, because I don't think Windows can use an ext4 formatted partition.  I am not 100% sure of that though.

As you can tell, I am certainly no Linux expert, but with a great deal of study and prep, and the help of people on this site, I managed to do this installation without any problems.  Some of the advice I followed was in answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591193/install-ubuntu-alongside-win-8-1-on-separate-physical-drives-and-dual-boot).