# Where should I install the boot loader on a second drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

So I recently installed a second hard drive in my laptop. Previously, I had split 1 hard drive into a windows and ubuntu partition, but after running out of space on each, I installed this new hard drive and installed ubuntu 14.04 on it. All of that went smoothly, but now when I load up the boot menu, I'm not seeing the option to boot into this new ubuntu installation.

It seems that my bios is set to only look at the first hard drive? Here are my thoughts:

1) Update my bios to find my second grub install. (don't know how to do that)

2) Reinstall ubuntu with drive 1 as the bootloader location (I'm afraid I'll overwrite the old grub and be unable to boot into my old ubuntu install)

3) Something else?

Sidenote: I'm using windows 10. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Did you run sudo update-grub on your old Ubuntu install?  That might pick up the new installation on the second disk.

Comment: @ubfan1 I haven't yet. I'll try that.

Comment: An answer to this question (http://askubuntu.com/questions/591193/install-ubuntu-alongside-win-8-1-on-separate-physical-drives-and-dual-boot) states that you must disable "Fastboot/General Optimization" for this to work.

Comment: @ubfan1 wow well now I feel silly. I hadn't thought to boot my old ubuntu install since I didn't think it would be picked up, but good ol' grub got it. Thank you!!

Comment: @OrganicMarble I just checked, and fast boot is in fact disabled for me, which I guess explains why this works. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)