# Windows 10 Loads Up Directly, No GRUB Menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bootloader

I was trying to get rid of that GRUB bootloader and wanted to use the Windows 10 bootloader. In order to do that, I did this:

I opened CMD and then put: bcdboot C:\Windows in it.

Now, the problem I'm facing is that Windows 10 directly loads up when I start my PC, no GRUB or Windows bootloader :(

How to fix this?

PS: I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Ashu I assumed that he unable to boot into ubuntu. But no response from him.

Comment: This seems more like an issue with Windows than Ubuntu, as the user cannot get the Windows bootloader to work correctly.

Comment: Before you follow any recovery advice, it's imperative that you determine your Windows boot mode, as described [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html), among other places. I suspect you're booting in EFI mode, in which case [this question and answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/678536/will-installing-windows-break-grub-in-this-case) re relevant and you should ignore the answers already posted by isuru-buddhika and Ryko, both of which assume a BIOS-mode installation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

at first install the free software 'EasyBCD' (current version is 2.2) in your windows 10 system. Then run it. In EasyBCD, click on "**Add New Entry**" and select "**Linux/BSD**" and change the type to "**GRUB 2**" and name it "**Ubuntu**". And then Click on "**Add Entry**". Go to "Edit Boot Menu" and click on "**Save settings**". And then you are good to go. You can also change the order of boot menu during power up from the "Edit Boot Menu" option.
[image]

Comment: Can't use those options: http://prntscr.com/a3v4ub

Comment: This answer assumes a BIOS-mode installation, which is likely an invalid assumption, given that it's a Windows 10 computer. Following this advice on an EFI-mode computer will not work and may create new problems.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you install windows on a machines with Ubuntu as Windows replaces the GRUB with it's own boot-loader. And by running bcdboot you have done the same. You need to update GRUB in order to get back to Ubuntu. Then you'll be able to use both Windows ans Ubuntu from GRUB. Tested this with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1. Should work for Win 10 also.

What you will need:

- Live Ubuntu Disk/USB
- Basic understanding with Ubuntu Terminal

How To:

- Boot from live disk/usb and select `Try Ubuntu Without Installing`.
- Go to the terminal `Ctrl+Alt+T`
- Enter the following commands correctly.

  1. `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` Please replace `sda1` with your Ubuntu partition.
  2. `sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`
     `sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts`
     `sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc`
     `sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys`
  3. `sudo chroot /mnt` Go to the root folder of your installation
  4. `grub-install /dev/sda` Reinstall GRUB
  5. `update-grub` Updating GRUB.
  6. `exit` Exit from chroot system
  7. Unmount what you have previously mounted
     `sudo umount /mnt/sys
     sudo umount /mnt/proc
     sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts
     sudo umount /mnt/dev
     sudo umount /mnt`
  8. Restart the system.

Source : [How to Repair, Restore, or Reinstall Grub 2 with a Ubuntu Live CD or USB](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: This answer assumes a BIOS-mode installation, which is likely an invalid assumption, given that it's a Windows 10 computer. Following this advice on an EFI-mode computer will not work and may create new problems.

Answer (score 0):

Assume nothing goes both ways, the Windows 10 installation should always be checked out to be sure which type of install you are dealing with first MBR (Bios/Legacy or GPT (UEFI).  Attempting to change your Windows installation from MBR to GPT is looking for unnecessary head aches.  I have Win10 machines and everyone of them Windows installed in Bios/legacy mode, all 4 machines were Windows 7 upgrade to Windows 10 installs.  This is actually fairly common on older machines running Windows 7 that are upgraded to Windows 10.