# Two hard drives, WIN10 have already installed, now I want to install ubuntu to the other SSHD

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

My computer has two hard drives, I have installed win10 in the SSD for working and gaming and other stuff, and I would like to install Ubuntu on the other drive, which is a 1T SSHD. I have set 3 volume on the SSHD and I want to install Ubuntu in the Ubuntu(D).

I have searched online and been told that mis-installation might cause that you can either open win or Ubuntu without giving choice or can't even start your computer.

So, any one knows how to install Ubuntu in other drive while win10 has been installed? I am totally new to Ubuntu. What I want after installation is that there would be a step after starting computer that I can choose which system I am going to use.

My motherboard is asus z170, using UEFI, and CPU is i5 6500. Win10 60-bit is installed.
[Hard dirve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg7mE.png)

Comment: If Windows is installed in UEFI boot mode, be sure to install Ubuntu to a gpt partitioned drive. Is sdb gpt? Ubuntu cannot install to NTFS formatted partition anyway.  And best to create an ESP - efi system partition at beginning of drive, but even if you specify grub in Something Else to install to sdb, it will install the the ESP on sda. You can disconnect sda to get an install only on sdb. With both drives connected only use Something Else.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/591193/install-ubuntu-alongside-win-8-1-on-separate-physical-drives-and-dual-boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it is recommended to install all your operating systems on the same hard disk drive.

If nevertheless you want to install Ubuntu to another drive you can do it, if you really want to.

Boot into Windows, disable hibernation and fast boot before you start the Ubuntu installation.

When starting Ubuntu installer choose **Something else** and select the other drive for Ubuntu.

**IMPORTANT** : Install the boot loader to the same drive where you installed Windows before !

Note : You can select the operating system you want to boot from **GRUB menu** when finished.

**Update** with a **detailed explanation** requested in the **comment** of **Luffy Tse** :

To disable hibernation open **command prompt as administrator** and execute :

```
powercfg /h off
```

To disable Fast Boot open **Control Panel** (the old version - not the modern design),
select the **Energy Settings**, enable **show hidden settings** and **uncheck Fast Boot**.

After these disabling actions **shutdown** the machine (do **NOT reboot**) completely.

Comment: Thanks for your help~ And "disable hibernation and fast boot", how should I do it? I am not familiar with the BIOS or UEFI system.