# How to dual boot windows 8.1 and Ubuntu Trusty when both the OS are on Different HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

Before you mark this as duplicate try to understand my question.

I have 2 HDD.

1. 500 GB with Windows 8.1 installed (UEFI BIOS).
2. 1 TB with Ubuntu Trusty installed (UEFI BIOS).

The windows was installed 2 years ago and recently installed the Ubuntu using USB drive by purchasing a new 1 TB HDD.

I have selected the boot loader for Ubuntu as the 1 TB.
Installation was fine and I am able to run Ubuntu.

Issue: Every time I have to change the Boot Order in the UEFI Bios to boot into the respective OS. I do not have the Dual Boot screen coming up where I can choose between Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu.

Option Tried: Installed a GRUB Partioner s/w but could not find the windows entry there. added a screen shot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy9h8.png)

I have read lot of options but I am still not clear on this particular case.
Please help.

Comment: Did you partition the new drive with gpt and include an ESP - efi system partition? Or did you install in BIOS boot with MBR partitions. Or worse MBR partitions but UEFI boot thru ESP on Windows drive. Post this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info UEFI install: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI (best with Windows disconnected) OR: http://askubuntu.com/questions/591193/install-ubuntu-alongside-win-8-1-on-separate-physical-drives-and-dual-boot

Comment: Sorry  I am new to Ubuntu and its terms associated. I choose the option "Something Else". and then I did partitioning on the sdb which had 1 TB free space. It asked me to add a partition for EFI, so I did /dev/sdb7 efi 50MB.

Comment: In first post above include this: `sudo parted -l` Even with UEFI you may have Windows in BIOS mode. If so then you will not be able to boot Windows from grub which is in UEFI boot mode. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible and you can only dual boot from grub, systems installed in same boot mode.

Comment: animesh@ani-pc:~$ sudo parted -l
Warning: /dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.
However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.
Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT
partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an
msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?
Yes/No?

What shall I enter, any Idea.

Comment: Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt partitioned drives. Did you reinstall Windows in BIOS boot. When Windows converts a gpt partitioned drive to MBR, it does it incorrectly and leaves the backup gpt partition table. Linux sees both MBR & gpt and gets confused. But then Windows is in BIOS boot mode and you cannot boot BIOS Windows from UEFI Ubuntu/grub.

Comment: oldfred is probably on the right track. To cut out the guesswork, though, please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) on your computer. This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post it to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL it provides here. This will give us the sort of detailed information we need for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Update the bootloader - boot into Ubuntu and open up a terminal by pressing 
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run this command in terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This command will scan for installed operating systems on your Hard Drives and partitions and add them to the boot menu.

Reboot and change the boot order so that the Linux Hard Drive boots first.

Comment: I tried this command sudo update-grub. but no use.  Also I want to mention both has UEFI BIOS. Also the fast boot option was disabled.

animesh@ani-pc:~$ sudo update-grub
 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-33-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-33-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-25-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done

Comment: Seems Ubuntu is not able to find Windows as the other operating system. as I gave the output of the sudo update-grud command above.