# Is the dual boot possible when Ubuntu & Windows installed on different disks?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

I want to install Ubuntu on my SSD (let it be `DISK1`), and Windows on my SATA one (let it be `DISK2`). My plan is to install Ubuntu later than Windows (as it is suggested) and choose the OS I am going to use from GRUB by booting from `DISK1`.

I do not want to create partitions on my SSD since its size is limited and not big enough to handle 2 operating systems when it is divided.

I would like to learn if it is possible. If so, how can I make them work properly - especially after GRUB updates?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, I did just that. Follow the advice in both the answer and oldfred's comment to this question. https://askubuntu.com/questions/591193/install-ubuntu-alongside-win-8-1-on-separate-physical-drives-and-dual-boot

Comment: Thanks, I'll. But how did you install GRUB on a FAT32 partition? Can you post a comment that describes the order of this installation? @OrganicMarble

Comment: My PC was preinstalled with windows so it already had an EFI boot partition on the first hard drive (sda).  When I partitioned the 2nd drive (sdb) for Ubuntu, I added an EFI boot partition there, and when I installed using Something Else option, I chose it as boot.  But the installer put the Ubuntu EFI boot stuff in the prexisting EFI partition on sda and ignored the one I made - and that all worked fine.  I've read since in comments on this site that the installer will always use the EFI partition on sda regardless of what you tell it.

Comment: So if you are installing from scratch, put your EFI boot partition on sda as the 1st partition. That's what oldfred was telling me in his comment but I didn't understand.  If you format it as FAT32 and set the boot flag the installer should use it as the EFI partition.

Comment: So if you install Windows first, the Windows installer should create the EFI boot partition and the Ubuntu installer should use it when you install Ubuntu later.