# Questions about running off an external USB

Tags: usb

So I'm thinking of setting up a full install of ubuntu on an external drive, however I have a few questions about how to do it first. Bear in mind I'm a newcomer to linux so if there's some common rule or fact, it's a fair assumption I won't know it.

1. How simple is the installation? I've been googling it but the majority of results are about live usbs, and I want a full install. So long as I'm careful is there much chance I might install it on the wrong drive? That seems to be a common warning I come across. And if I were to accidentally install it on my internal drive, assuming I have plenty of free space, is there a risk of data loss?
2. How big is the installation? Just trying to decide what size of USB to get while allowing for enough space for my files.
3. How possible will it be to run applications and even games from it? I realise there'll be a large performance hit just from the fact it's running from external, but I'm not planning on trying anything too intensive, so should I be able to cope with running the basics?
4. If needs be, would I be able to easily access any documents I save on the external stick from windows/any other operating system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator) In order to find the answers to all of your questions, please search in all 17of the answers to the linked question.

Comment: First will it be UEFI or BIOS boot? And then best to partition in advance, so you plan your partitions and use Something Else to install as grub's default install is to drive seen as sda.  I have installed to a 8GB / partition with another 8 GB data partition, but now 32 or even 64GB flash drives are inexpensive. If you have lots of RAM, one an application loads it runs at full speed. It is writes that a slow. Best to use USB3 flash drive on USB3 port. IF newer UEFI: http://askubuntu.com/questions/591193/install-ubuntu-alongside-win-8-1-on-separate-physical-drives-and-dual-boot

Comment: Why? If you're planning on using that installation on different computers, lots of things will be configured for the hardware it was originally installed on. Trying to boot that installation on different hardware is likely to lead you to Unhappyland.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this in a different order than you asked because it makes more sense that way.

A live USB simply means that you'll install Ubuntu from the USB. You only need a USB large enough to hold the .iso. After you finish installing, it's on your hard drive and all you have to do is run it, so yes, applications and games can be run from there. Next, I'll explain installation for you.

First, your USB only has to be 4 GB (that's the most common one so it's great). Before you start, make sure you have a .iso downloaded (a disc image). If you're looking for one to use, click this [link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/). Make sure you download the right one. You should be running 64-bit. Next (I assume you run Windows?), you'll download [this](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) lovely peice of software. Install and run it. You'll get something that looks like this:

[image]

Notice the how all the options are. Make sure yours looks for something like this. All you really need to do is choose the correct device (whatever your USB is) and then go down to "Create a bootable disk using." Make sure "ISO image" is selected and then click the button next to it. It'll take you to File Explorer. Navigate to your .iso file and select it.  Check start and let it run. When you finish, open the USB and run Wubi. Select install when you get there.

Comment: I know the difference between live and full installs, and I'm looking for help running a full install.

Comment: You obviously don't. My first installation of Ubuntu was from live USB. All a live USB is is a USB with a .iso on it so you can install an OS. You can do it with any OS, Windows, Fedora, etc. Just do what I said in the question and your installation will work just fine.