# Do UEFI dual boot OS's need to be on the same physical disk?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

On my old laptop, which had one large SSD and no secondary drive, came with windows 10. I used window's disk manager to un-allocate about 100 gb, and installed Ubuntu from a bootable USB drive. It was fine. It boots fine. No problems.

My new laptop however is giving me some issues. It has a small SSD (in windows, C drive) which holds Windows 10 and has almost no room for anything else. It has a secondary large regular HDD (in windows, D drive). I tried to do the same procedure. I partitioned off some space on the D drive and installed ubuntu from a bootable USB (the same drive in fact, I never erased it). It seemed fine at first. However after installing ubuntu and rebooting I found that grub goes to a command line instead of the "select your operating system" screen. In fact the behavior is basically identical to this post:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot

(sadly, none of the comments in that post fixed my issue, and it's a year old so I didnt want to hijack a dead thread)

I can still boot to either ubuntu or windows if I mash F2 when booting up. That takes me to the bios screen. I exit without doing anything and it goes to the normal grub OS selection screen, instead of a command line.

If I change the boot order in BIOS to have windows first, then it boots windows just fine with no grub screen, but, of course, then I can't get to ubuntu at all.

Could this be because the two OS's are on different physical disks? Perhaps something in the hardware is looking for an OS on the disk windows labeled C, but the boot order tries to load ubuntu first which is on disk D?

Comment: was grub installed to the EFI partition of the SSD? and verify that ubuntu was installed in EFI mode. A grub command line usually means that grub cannot find it's config file.

Comment: I don't believe that anything was installed to the SSD. I think I installed everything on the unallocated 100 gb on the secondary HDD.

Comment: In EFI mode, the EFI System partition is mounted to /boot/efi. If this did not occur then ubuntu is installed in Legacy Mode. Legacy boot can not read a GPT partitioned disk. Although EFI should be able to handle a separate EFI partition for each internal disk, implementations can be buggy. You can use gparted to see which partitions your system mounts.

Comment: If SSD is that small is it really just the hiberfile for Windows? Many systems with 16 or 32GB SSD were used just for that. And then only the amount of RAM was actually used on SSD and some users installed all of Ubuntu in remaining space. Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: @oldfred The SSD is 128 gb, it has the windows OS and a few other things that I need to load quickly. It's not just a hibernate/system state storage. In fact  the SSD is named "OS" and the HDD is named "DATA" (these are the names they from the factory, I see no need to change them)

I have deleted the ubuntu partition and am going to try reinstalling and making sure it's in the partition I thought it was, and in EFI mode. I think it was the first time, but can't hurt to double check. If need be I'll try gparted and sudo parted -l.

Comment: Ubuntu only installs its UEFI grub to drive seen as sda or first NVMe drive. Usually in the same ESP - efi system partition as Windows, no matter what drive you install Ubuntu into. But I suggest using gpt & include an ESP on every drive is using UEFI to boot. Be sure to only partition with gparted and use Something Else. Only use Windows on NTFS partitions and reboot if resizing NTFS and run chkdsk before anything else. Make sure Windows fast start up is off.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/JHZu5QQ.png

This is what my partitions are. The first disk (the 128 gb ssd) has 
1: Windows boot
2: Windows reserved 
3: Spare space for data, which I would prefer to remain for windows, although I guess I should put Ubuntu here if I needed to
4: I'm not even sure what this is

The other disk has
1: Big data block for windows
2: I think this is the ubuntu OS?
3: Ubuntu data storage
4: Ubuntu swap space

Windows fast startup, and UEFI/Bios secure boot, are off.

Comment: Your 4 is a windows recovery image just like the one on my sda below.  I strongly suggest you read the answer to the question I linked to in my answer below if you are getting a `no device found` error.

Answer (score 0):

No, they do not. My system is a counter-example.

You can see from the gparted shots that the ESP and Windows partitions are on sda, and the Ubuntu partition is on sdb.

[image]

[image]

See also [Install Ubuntu alongside Win 8.1 on separate physical drives and dual-boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591193/install-ubuntu-alongside-win-8-1-on-separate-physical-drives-and-dual-boot)

And yes, my root partition is ludicrously big. But it does not matter.