# Dual boot in different hard disks. Is that a problem?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

today i installed ubuntu 18.04 alongside windows 10. The problem is that although windows 10 is installed at nvme(512gb), when i was installing ubuntu i was only able to use my second hard drive which is an a ssd(256gb). I think that happened because installer was seeing that my windows bootloader was installed at ssd(thats impossible because i added the second hard drive after i had done windows 10 installation). So now windows 10 is at nvme, and ubuntu and grub  at ssd. Is there a problem with that? is this making booting slower? Should i do something?Thanks in advace
[image: hard drives]

Comment: An nvme drive is potentially faster than an ssd but it depends on exactly what drives you are comparing. How long is your Ubuntu boot time? Does it feel slow? If not I’d leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

My dual boot setup has windows and Ubuntu on two different physical drives.

I have not encountered any problems because of this setup, which I did in 2015.

I asked about this setup here: [Install Ubuntu alongside Win 8.1 on separate physical drives and dual-boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591193/install-ubuntu-alongside-win-8-1-on-separate-physical-drives-and-dual-boot)