# Installing Ubuntu on a Primary Partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

I'm new to ubuntu and I don't want to erase all my data from the hard drive by mistake, but I want to know if there is any problems if I install it on a Primary Partition, https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxIvr.png
I have my C\ on which is my Windows 10 on my SSD
and I want to install it in my G:\ partition that is on my HDD in which I had my old windows partition before moving to SSD.

My question is, can I install it directly to the G:\ partition or I need to delete that and make a Unallocatted space?

Comment: Mistakes can happen despite everybody's best intentions. The best protection for anything you value is a complete backup.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/591193/install-ubuntu-alongside-win-8-1-on-separate-physical-drives-and-dual-boot

Comment: @Raul Rusu Backup, then verify the backup matches the source. Backup again to different media or the cloud. Verify that backup. Take a deep breath and feel confident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Ubuntu tutorial](http://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0) gives you a step by step guide through the installation process.

However, let's make sure we're clear on something first: There are no drive letters in Linux or UNIX.  Instead of using G: to install, you will erase the G: partition and turn that into a Linux-friendly partition, in step **6 Allocate drive space**.

Windows uses either the FAT type (FAT, FAT12, FAT16, FAT32, exFAT) of disk partitions, or NTFS (nowadays, almost always NTFS).  Linux uses the ext (ext2, ext3, ext4) as well as less popular disk partitions (XFS, btrfs, and others); here is a [primer on the subject](http://linuxbsdos.com/2014/11/08/a-beginners-guide-to-disks-and-disk-partitions-in-linux/).

So, in step **6 Allocate Disk Space**, you will choose **Something Else**. You will choose the NTFS partition **G:** for deletion, then tell the Ubuntu partitioning program [gparted](https://gparted.org/) to go ahead and actually delete it. Then, you will tell gparted to take that empty space and use it for the "[root](http://www.linfo.org/slash_root.html)' or **/** directory of Linux, then tell it to go ahead and do it.

**/** is the top level directory of Linux, and the files you boot with go underneath it, as well as your Linux data files.

You will also be asked where to put [grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2), the program which lets you choose which OS to boot with. Tell it **/dev/sda** .

FYI, there is no 'root' user in Ubuntu for safety's sake; you will learn about that later, if you have not already, how Ubuntu uses [sudo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/sudo_root.8.html) to enable you to do things which could be dangerous if done wrong.

Comment: thank you very much for the help I'll try it today, maybe I'll do it in VM just to see how everything goes.