# What happens to my second hard drive when i install ubuntu alongside windows on first?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have 2 hard drives on my PC 500GB ssd where i have win10 installed and 1TB GB hdd drive. Now i want to dual boot ubuntu onto ssd.

The question is:

- what happens to the hdd drive, will it be accessible only from windows or both OSs or do i have to create some partitions there for ubuntu to access?

Sorry if I mixed up/wrote something unwise(feel free to point out), im complete newbie.

Comment: Is Windows installed in UEFI boot mode? Then you must installs Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. You do need to have Windows fast start up off, for Linux NTFS driver to be able to read it. But often better to have shared NTFS data partition, so Ubuntu not writing into the Windows system partition. Similar: http://askubuntu.com/questions/591193/install-ubuntu-alongside-win-8-1-on-separate-physical-drivess-and-dual-boot  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator Some brands or models may need UEFI settings changed.

Answer (score -1):

It depends.

If you don't do anything with the hdd then Ubuntu should till be able to read any files on it if Windows is shut down completely, not just as fast start.

Most people who have/like a lot of files, will format/partition part of the hdd for the home partition of Ubuntu for their files, only needing ~40GBs for root.